# Convert NULL to Blank on a table

Tags: sql-server, database

I have column that is define like this `Rate Numeric(7,2), Null`. This column have some data in it, but I need to replace the NULL with blank. I have tried this

```
Update [Customer]  
Set  Rate = ' '    
where Rate IS NULL ;
```

And the Error is:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 12 Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

I need to replace NULL with Blank.

Comment: Would you be so kind to clarify,what you mean under "blank"-value for NUMERIC-column? It can not be an empty string ' '.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What does `a blank` even mean for a numeric column? An empty string is simply invalid for a numeric column. The "blank" value in SQL *is* the NULL value. A *default* value like `0` is not the same as having no value at all, `NULL`. If `rate` refers to a rating, `0` is a *bad* choice because it would affect the average rating. In this case `NULL` may be the best option

Comment: I am trying to make where i have NULL in the column to be Blank anytime i run a select statement. Thanks

Comment: You can set it to 0, not to an empty string, that fundamentally doesn't make sense as it is a number column and won't accept arbitrary strings

Answer (score 4):

You can't store character data (a blank) in a numeric data type column. The value must be either NULL or a valid numeric value within the specified precision/scale.

Converting `NULL` to blank is a job for the presentation layer.

Comment: I am trying to make where i have NULL in the column to be Blank

Comment: Yes, and that's application logic, @JermaineBash, not SQL's. A blank string (`''`) is not a valid numerical value and thus can't be stored in a column which is numerical data type; such as `numeric`.

Comment: You could specify an expression like `COALESCE(CAST(YourColumn AS varchar(20)), '')` in the `SELECT` query to return a string, with `NULL` converted to empty string.  But it would be better to apply formatting rules like that in the application code.

Answer (score 0):

**There are many ways to replace null values.**

1. You can replace while selecting in database,
   for example:  **select isnull(Rate,'') from customer**
2. You can replace in your logic layer or presentation layer.
   **`if(rate is null) { rate = ''; }`**